# Drupal Commerce - (free) Shipping , Pickup option , Order Comment?

Tags: commerce

I'm still facing some issues with my Drupal Commerce.

The shop is only available for authenticated users. When they want to checkout they should be able to pick a shipping option or a pickup option.

When the order total is less than 25 euro and they want to get it deliverd they will be a shipping fee of x euro's. When it is higher than 25 euro shipping will be free. When they pick the option to pick it up, it will be free.

I also want in both cases that a text fields appears so they can give a date/time that they want the package to be delivered.

I also have customer profiles enabled, but when I'm at the checkout my profile isn't getting filled in.

Any thoughts on how to achieve this?

Best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Install https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_flat_rate
- Go to "admin/commerce/config/shipping/methods" and create following flat rate services

  - Pickup at store (0 $)
  - Free shipping (0 $)
  - Shipping (x $)
- Configure the last 2 flat services (free shipping / shipping) by clicking "configure component"

  - Free shipping rate -> add condition "Order amount comparison" >= 25 $
  - Shipping -> add same condition, but check "negate"

Now picking up at store will always show up, the other 2 depending the order amount.

For the textfields, you can put that in the shipping profile for the customer.